# Android form validation using reactive programming

Tags: android, forms, rx-java, observable, rx-android

I'm fairly new to RxJava, RxAndroid. I have two `editText` one for password and one for password confirmation. Basically I need to check if the two strings match. Is it possible to do this using `Observables`? Would really appreciate an example so I can grasp it. Cheers.

Comment: What is your general approach? Do you want to react to changes in the edit texts reactively, or do you the view to react to the validation results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create `Observable` out of your `EditText`. You can utilize [`RxBinding`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) library or write wrappers by yourself.

```
Observable<CharSequence> passwordObservable = 
                      RxTextView.textChanges(passwordEditText);
Observable<CharSequence> confirmPasswordObservable = 
                      RxTextView.textChanges(confirmPasswordEditText);
```

Then merge your streams and validate values using [`combineLatest`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#combineLatest-io.reactivex.ObservableSource-io.reactivex.ObservableSource-io.reactivex.functions.BiFunction-) operator:

```
Observable.combineLatest(passwordObservable, confirmPasswordObservable, 
    new BiFunction<CharSequence, CharSequence, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(CharSequence c1, CharSequence c2) throws Exception {
            String password = c1.toString;
            String confirmPassword = c2.toString;
            // isEmpty checks needed because RxBindings textChanges Observable
            // emits initial value on subscribe
            return !password.iEmpty() && !confirmPassword.isEmpty() 
                                      && password.equals(confirmPassword);
        }
    })
    .subscribe(new Consumer<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Boolean fieldsMatch) throws Exception {
             // here is your validation boolean!
             // for example you can show/hide confirm button
             if(fieldsMatch) showConfirmButton();
             else hideCOnfirmButton();
        }
    }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
            // always declare this error handling callback, 
            // otherwise in case of onError emission your app will crash
            // with OnErrorNotImplementedException
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

`subscribe` method returns `Disposable` object. You have to call `disposable.dispose()` in your `Activity`'s `onDestroy` callback (or `OnDestroyView` if you are inside `Fragment`) in order to avoid memory leaks.

**P.S.** The example code uses `RxJava2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding)   library to do something like this.

```
  Observable
            .combineLatest(RxTextView.textChanges(passwordView1),
                          RxTextView.textChanges(passwordView2), 
                          (password1, password2) -> checkPasswords))
            .filter(aBoolean -> aBoolean)
            .subscribe(aBoolean -> Log.d(passwords match))
```